# SSRS link to a PDF file

Tags: reporting-services

I have report that shows invoices with link to file server to the specific invoice as PDF.
I have the column set as following for example: file://FILESERVER/INVOICES/2019/38/947/3894798.pdf

It is set as Go to URL. When I click the link, nothing happens.
When I right click and open in new tab I get "about:blank#blocked"
When I copy the link and paste it in a new window, it works just fine.

Any ideas how could I make it work with just clicking the link and it would open the file?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

OK so I figured it out. It is not a problem with the SSRS, but with the local files and browsers. Browsers like Chrome, MS Edge, FIrefox etc. do not support opening local file links. After a day of digging thru the internet the solution is to install an extension for example Enable local file links for Google Chrome.